# how to add blank space between master <tr> in Jquery jtable

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-jtable

I m trying to do something like this:

[image: Example screenshot of a table]

I tried editing `jtable.js` file adding `margin-bottom:50px;` in `tr > jtable-data-row`, but no success.

How can I get this done?

Comment: use padding-bottom instead of margin-bottom...

Comment: tried doing that but seems that padding and margin doesn't work

Comment: any chance to give us a bit of the rendered code (from the browser, not the raw code)... or setup a [JsBin](http://jsbin.com) with some example...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below CSS in your code:

```
table {
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:0 10px;
}
```

Comment: It gives this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Z8wRWgJWpRR0RfMXo5MVFrWVE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: border-spacing: 0 10px should be as you wish.